# Carousel is not sliding

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with my carousel. It won't slide. I have tried so much that my head is hurting. The problem is that it's only staying on one pic and the arrows is not working.

Including files:

```
<head> 
    <!--- START Styles --->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/mywebside/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/mywebside/index.css" type="text/css" />
    <!--- END Styles --->
    <!--- START Scripts --->
    <script type="text/javascript" src"http://localhost/mywebside/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src"http://localhost/mywebside/js/carousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel() 
})
    </script>
    <!--- END Scripts --->
</head>
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item"> <img src="img/Wood.png"></div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="img/Stone.png"></div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="img/dirt.png"></div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
         </div>
```

Comment: Have you checked console logs?

Comment: Yes nothing there @Curt

Comment: I don't think you need the carousel.js if you already include the bootstrap.js

Comment: I did remove it and its still the same :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your scripting order and try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src"http://localhost/mywebside/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src"http://localhost/mywebside/js/carousel.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src"http://localhost/mywebside/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src"http://localhost/mywebside/js/carousel.js"></script>
```

2nd Try

Add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
```

Its working in the this [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tf6S7/6/)

Comment: Its still the same @FaceOfJock

Comment: Have added this css in that fiddle `bootstrap-combined.min.css` So try adding that ..Hope it works

Comment: When i press F12 it says only Under Scripts jquery.js not bootstrap @FaceOfJock

Comment: Try the online link `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify in the options when you call the carousel? The default for bootstrap carousel (I'm assuming that you are using this) is 5000ms (5 seconds). By default it will also automatically pause if your mouse is hovering over it.

Try specifying a shorter interval span to test it out, and make sure your mouse isn't hovering over it.

```
var options = { interval: 1000 };
$('.carousel').carousel(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace the jquery.min file
It worked for my file
Thank u.